# Sensu /checks API call appears empty

Tags: docker, sensu

I am running Sensu as a series of Docker containers (`sensu-server`, `sensu-api`, n `sensu-client`s, `rabbitmq` and `redis`). While the clients successfully register themselves and run checks requested by the server, and whose checks will be reported via handlers and via `/clients`, API calls to `/checks` return nothing.

Server config:

```
{
  "rabbitmq":{
    "host": "rabbitmq"
  },
  "redis":{
    "host":"redis"
  },
  "api":{
    "host":"api",
    "port":4567
  }
  "handlers": { ... },
  "checks": { ... }
}
```

API config:

```
{
  "rabbitmq":{
    "host":"rabbitmq"
  },
  "redis":{
    "host":"redis"
  },
  "api":{
    "host":"api",
    "port":4567
  }
}
```

Client config:

```
{
  "client":{
    "name":"openshift-{{ .Env.AVAILABILITY_ZONE }}",
    "address":"{{ .Env.HOSTNAME }}",
    "subscriptions":[
        "{{ .Env.AVAILABILITY_ZONE }}",
        "any-client"
    ]
  },
  {
    "rabbitmq":{
      "host":"rabbitmq"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in a similar scenario - our configuration didn't give the api & servers (which ran inside separate docker containers) a copy of the check definitions.

Here's the Github issue that lead me to it: https://github.com/sensu/uchiwa/issues/83#issuecomment-51917336